# Vue.js vuetify CSS3 cannot align vertically a span element with the middle of a button

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have currently tried to set the vertical-align CSS to middle but it does not output as I would like.. thanks for feedback

```
       <template>
        <!-- block to be tested -->
        <div data-v-5a5e3060="" class="layout row">
            <div data-v-5a5e3060="" class="flex xs12">
                <div data-v-5a5e3060="" class="text-xs-center">
                    <button data-v-5a5e3060="" type="button" class="btn btn--round">
                        <div class="btn__content">Clear</div>
                    </button>
                    <button data-v-5a5e3060="" type="submit" class="btn btn--round">
                        <div class="btn__content">LOGIN!<i data-v-5a5e3060="" aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--right material-icons">lock_open</i></div>
                    </button>
                    <span data-v-5a5e3060="">Link to Forgot password?</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>



    <style scoped lang="scss">
    span {
      float: right;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    </style>
```

[image: This output :]

Comment: Why did you post generated html and use css if you are looking for vuetify solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use flex on the container element of the buttons and span, for instance:

```
.action-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Also if using Vuetify, have a look [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/grid), there are inbuilt flex directives, so you can apply them directly on the container element without writing any additional CSS. For example, there's an `align-center` prop you can use.

Comment: Thanks a lot ...  I am just discovering vuetify  ( first project)

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the following CSS to the span tag:

```
span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

If it doesn't work add `position: relative` to the container div

Comment: thanks Fabio for your feedback... 8bit's answer seems to be more indicated with flex uage